# What was so bad about the what happened to the Borg drones?

Tags: star-trek, borg, star-trek-picard

In *Star Trek: Picard*, episode 8, we see the following happening to a huge amount of Borg drones:

> They get blown out into the vacuum. From what we know of the Borg though, they should easily be able to suffer this fate without any adverse effects. As Borg drones suffer no ill effects from vacuum as we know from *Star Trek: First Contact* and other media. So given this and there being transporters on the cube, one could easily state that they could have been transported back onto the cube without problems.

But instead it seemed as if the Collective saw the fate of these drones as irreversible and bad.

Am I overlooking something here about the Borg or is there an error in the script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not all of the drones were still in a drone state. By blowing them outside the cube, they were potentially jeopardizing the ones who had been reclaimed.

Then there's the fact that Seven had fired them all up to use them to fight against the Zhat Vash. Having your whole army jettisoned into space (even if they wouldn't be harmed by it) wasn't good for *her* (not to mention she basically made herself a Borg Queen for the purpose of doing that, something she wasn't sure she'd be able to pull herself out of). It was understandable why she'd be upset about that.

As we see later

> several drones managed to re-board the ship and stop some of the Zhat Vash

Comment: I have to admit, I was scared for Seven being able to get out once she was plugged in as a borg queen. I was afraid there’d be either a no-going back moment or a significant relapse even after being unplugged for all those years.  It was both exciting and worrisome at the same time.